# Deserialize JSON with RestSharp

Tags: c#, json, rest

I am making a request to `http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json` using `RetSharp` like so:

```
        var request = new RestSharp.Serializers.Newtonsoft.Json.RestRequest();
        request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        var client = new RestClient(URL + urlParameters);
        client.Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy; // I was led to believe this will fix my problem of my requests taking minutes on end to execute, but it didn't that much.
        var queryResult = client.Execute(request).Content;
        var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CurrentJsonResponse>(queryResult);
```

This works fine but I don't like that I have to make a separate call to `JsonConvert`, and, supposedly, RestSharp should have support for that kind of thing built-in.

I tried the following:

```
        var response = client.Execute<CurrentJsonResponse>(request).Data; // returns a CurrentJsonResponse object with null properties.

        request.JsonSerializer = new NewtonsoftJsonSerializer(); // I put it at the very start, but doesn't help.

        var jsonDeserializer = new JsonDeserializer();
        client.AddHandler("application/json", jsonDeserializer); // Second verse, same as the first.

        var response = client.Execute<object>(request).Data; // Correctly creates an annonymous object that has the right properties/information but it's not exactly what I'm going for. As I wanted it strongly-typed.
```

Nothing worked. How can I deserialize the json response I get with RestSharp explicitly, without a separate call to Newtonsoft. I have downloaded the `RestSharp.Serializers.Newtonsoft.Json` nuget.

Comment: Have you tried `var response = client.Execute<CurrentJsonResponse>(request).Data` or `var response = client.Execute<CurrentJsonResponse>(request)`?

Comment: @GuruStron, `var response = client.Execute<CurrentJsonResponse>(request).Data` is LITERALLY the first thing I have typed as tried. I think I also tried the other one but will test now and update.

Comment: [Doc](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Recommended-Usage) are pretty adamant that `Execute<T>(request).Data` should work =)

Comment: @GuruStron, just as I thought - I have tried `var response = client.Execute<CurrentJsonResponse>(request)`, however that just returns the request object, status code and all.

Comment: @GuruStron, I don't see any mention of newtonsoft deserialization in the given docs, but thankfully your answer is... well, the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second attempt try changing

```
 var jsonDeserializer = new JsonDeserializer();
 client.AddHandler("application/json", jsonDeserializer);
```

To

```
client.AddHandler("application/json", () => new RestSharp.Serializers.Newtonsoft.Json.NewtonsoftJsonSerializer());
```

And call:

```
var response = client.Execute<CurrentJsonResponse>(request).Data;
```

Answer (score 0):

The default deserialization should work fine, I only had to change some serialization settings during [post](https://github.com/shahriarhossain/BrowserStack.Screenshots.Net/blob/master/BrowserStack.Screenshots.Net/Helper/BaseOperation.cs) request.

```
   var request = new RestRequest();    
   var restClient = new RestClient(endPoint);

   request.Method = Method.GET;

   request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

   var response = restClient.Execute<T>(request);

       if (response.ErrorException != null)
       {
            //log the exception
            //throw exception;
       }
   return response.Data;
```

In my experience, I have seen the default deserialization does not produce the expected result, if the mapping class is not proper. Make sure, you have correctly converted the JSON response to its corresponding c# class.